# Определение отключившихся и зависших клиентов?

Tags: c#

Я бы хотел узнать как отслеживать события отключения и зависания клиентов для tcpListener. Первая мысль клиент раз в N-миллисекунд отправляет пакет (назовем его NetPing) и получает от сервера NetPong. С каждым NetPong сервер обновляет время последнего ответа, и проверяет его в отдельном потоке : `clients.where (c => Datetime.Now - c.updateTime > constN).foreach(c => c.Disconnect())`
Есть ли более простые и эффективные способы ?

Comment: Мне кажется, это два разных вопроса. Событие завершение сессии это одно, а механизм детекта зависшего клиента — совсем другое.

Comment: с чем вы хотите проверять connection